# What does sval mean in gdb?

Tags: c, gdb

GDB is showing the content of a register as

```
rbp            0x604420 0x604420 <sval>
```

What does sval mean? Does it means string val?

Comment: Probably not. The rbp register holds the stack base pointer, which points to the base of the current stack frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does sval mean?

It means that there is a symbol (given `x86_64` target, `0x604420` would usually mean it's a `.text` symbol) with that value in the binary, and `rbp` happens to point to that symbol.

You can run `nm your-binary | grep sval` and see that symbol.

> Does it means string val?

No, *nothing* of the sort.